# How to test css with media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Is there a way I can spoof the media in my browser? Specifically, if I have a stylesheet with media queries that don't match a desktop browser, how can I test them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test the `@media print` by printing a test page or for just about anything that you can think of you can just emulate the requirements using **Google Chrome's** `Inspect Element -> Settings -> Overrides -> Emulate CSS Media`

Comment: @avrahamcool yes, but there are time limits for accepting answers, so i couldnt do it right away unfortunately.